# Import schema-form on the app.module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-schema-form

I'm trying to use the [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md) on an angular project, but I am unable to import it on my app.module.ts. This is my configuration:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { schemaForm } from 'angular-schema-form';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    schemaForm
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, when I try to run the `ng serve` it complies correctly, but the browser displays an error saying the schemaForm is undefined: `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'`

I have installed the dependency correctly using npm-install, but I am not able to generate a single form. Reading the official documentation it says:

> load the schemaForm module in your module definition

And it shows an example of how to import it using: `angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm'])`. The problem is that I'm not starting my module using `angular.module`, but using the `@NgModule` bootstrapping method showed on code above. This project was created from scratch using the angular CLI command `ng new project`

Could someone guide me in the right direction on how to import and use the [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md)? Thank you.

Comment: The lib that you linked is for AngularJs.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is angularjs package. It is not built for angular. Please find some other package for schema form which os built for angular. Check [this link for your reference](https://github.com/makinacorpus/angular2-schema-form)

Comment: The ngUpgrade library makes it usable. The angular2-schema-form project is unrelated and has a modified schema structure.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the question of how to use **Angular Schema Form** with **Angular** when it is still only available for **AngularJS** you would need to use the [ngUpgrade](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade) library.

The ASF library will be upgraded to support Angular, but it is a time consuming process and may take a long time unless more people assist in the migration project.